# How to test if the first character in a symbol is a letter in lisp?

Tags: lisp, letters, character-properties

How to test if the first character in a symbol is a letter  in lisp?
I know it has something to do with the alpha-char-p function.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
(alpha-char-p (char (string 'my-symbol) 0))
```

[`string`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/a_string.htm)
converts a *string designator* to a string. Some comments here suggest
that it's too general and it's better to use
[`symbol-name`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_2.htm)
which will refuse to work with anything but symbols. I believe that an interface accepting string designators is a better match for a request for *the first character of a symbol*.

Comment: I would use `symbol-name` instead of `string` here since it is more specific.

Comment: Indeed, sds offers an improvement. To go into a little bit more detail, and to perhaps avoid confusion in the future, a symbol does not have a first character; its name, however, will. You access the name of a symbol with the function `SYMBOL-NAME`.